# Issue when scrolltofixed plugin switches to position: absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm having a problem using the scrolltofixed jquery plugin

https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed

i use:

```
$('#tostick').scrollToFixed({  limit: $('#app-footer').offset().top - $('#tostick').height() - 20});
```

my #tostick is inside a

```
 margin:0 auto
```

div container and as soon it hits the fixed footer and the script switches from fixed to absolute positioning it jumps out of the container because

```
left: 1107px
```

is applied, which is the distance to the left border of the browser window, instead of the left border of the centered div container. it tried to add:

```
offsetLeft: -$('#container').offset().left
```

which is completely ignored.
thanks in advance for any tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give more info we don't know what #tostick is. Obviously we need the whole JS, and related html and css. Have you tried moving the entire container div it its only purpose is to have a style of margin:0 auto? 
Also you can do:

```
 $('#tostick').bind('unfixed', function() { $(this).css('left', ''); });//or what it needs to look right
   $('#tostick').bind('fixed', function() { $(this).css('left', '1107px'); });//switch back to what it was
```

Comment: tnx. this worked for me, I changed some classes learning how to bing something to this event was all I needed, thank you

Comment: also, without .bind() `$('#tostick').scrollToFixed({
  unfixed: function() { $(this).css('left', ''); },
  fixed: function() { $(this).css('left', '1170px'); }
});`